# Каким образом можно обесцвечивания изображения но кроссбраузерно?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

```js
 $('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("grayscale")
});
```

```css
body{
    padding: 50px 10px;
}
img{
    border: 10px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #555;
}
img.grayscale{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#" title=""><img class="grayscale" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8380/8464961316_bff336e8b1.jpg" width="480" height="246" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

вот этот эффект я долго искал и действительно кроссбраузерный, но как на js сделать что бы изображение было чёрно белым а при hover становилось цветным? 
Или всё таки использовать два изображения?

Comment: можно использовать картинку - самый кроссбраузерный метод

Comment: как я ждал этот ответ - я так и думал - сделайте ответом - я сделаю его лучшим - но решение нашёл - щас проверяю на всех устройствах

Comment: @LenovoID: Зачем вы ховеры верстаете с помощью jQuery? Есть же стандартный CSS селектор `img:hover {   }`?

Comment: по тому что это кроссбраузерно - а придать class элементу на hover не возможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ведь проще сделать:

```
img:hover{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: И зачем добавлять класс? Вы хотите добавлять эффект к определенным картинкам? Вы ведь все равно в jquery выбираете селектор (img). В css можно задать тот же селектор для всех картинок или для конкретных. И это кроссбраузерно. И быстрее работает, чем через jquery

Comment: я же писал уже вроде - надо из чёрно белой делать цветную - я к примеру фильтр применил - а вот как на hover отменить ??

Comment: Виноват, не заметил. Значит пусть изначально img имеет -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%), а на :hover будет значение none или grayscale(0%). Вроде должно сработать. Пишу с телефона, не могу проверить

Comment: я так делал -  и к сожалению отменить не получается , писал :hover:filter(none); и так :hover:filter(0%); и как только не делал и самое лучшее это hover на jquery

Comment: Действительно, на IE ничего не работает

Comment: Нашел скрипт решающий эту проблему на IE11. http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-ie11/cross-browser-grayscale-ie11.zip